# What is the proper interview etiquette for a fresh graduate who's just entering the job market?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, fresher

A little bit of background context. I pursued a Bachelor's degree in Visual Communication before switching my field of study to Computer Science. I'm about to finish my second degree and I currently have no work experience in CS. Therefore, I'm also looking for advice on how to deal with technical interviews, apart from the basics.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific? You could be asking about anything from what to wear to the interview to explaining why you have no prior work experience.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to know how different the interview process is, from that of a designer. Is it much more formal (including the dress code)? What is needed apart from a Resume? Do I need a portfolio to demonstrate my coding skills? I've seen that in some places, it has become more of a necessity.

Comment: I don't know anything about a designer interview but you are almost certainly going to be writing some code on a whiteboard or on a computer. If you have a portfolio it should be on github or the like and it should be linked in your resume. Then the interviewers will have already reviewed it. Bringing a bunch of code printed on paper during the interview will not get your code read (the interviewers have no time for that.)

Comment: Read Cracking the Coding interview. It explains most of what a CS grad will need to know. It's great apart from the crap about turning up in shorts and sandals.

Answer (score 2):

Get suited and booted.

Read up about the company.

Have a good few questions to hand - about the technology, company.

Read the job spec.